# Python Soap response

Tags: python, soap

I`m newbee in python. I have try for days with no luck:(.
The respsonse working good when the name and adress are on the soap server. But some times the adress is --- on the soap server. How can I make --- response to None?

in my soap.py

```
import logging

from suds.client import Client

logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from urllib import getproxies


   def return_address( country_code, vat_number):

if country_code == None and vat_number == None:
    return None

VIES_URL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatSeice.wsdl"
client = Client(VIES_URL, proxy=getproxies())



response = client.service.checkVat(countryCode= country_code, vatNumber= vat_number)

return response

if __name__== '__main__':

address_returned = return_address(  None, None)#
print address_returned
#innan if not "address_returned:
if not address_returned:
    print address_returned['name']
    print address_returned['address']
```

And

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


import pymysql.cursors
import sys
import re
import os
from PIL import Image
import base64
import cStringIO


from soap import return_address


if __name__== '__main__':

#
dsn_database = "    
dsn_hostname = "localhost"      
dsn_port =                   
dsn_uid = 
dsn_pwd = 
#dsn_charset='utf8'

conn = pymysql.connect(host=dsn_hostname, user=dsn_uid, passwd=dsn_pwd, db=dsn_database, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
cursor=conn.cursor()




cursor.execute("SELECT `uid`, `vat_number`, `country` FROM test") 
rows = cursor.fetchall()
num_IDs = len( rows)
   cursor.execute("SELECT `uid`, `vat_number`, `company_adress`, `country`, `company_name` FROM oldcompany ")
rows2 = cursor.fetchall()
print rows2


for i in range (num_IDs):
    uID = str(rows[i][0])
    vat_number = str(rows[i][1])
    country_code = str(rows[i][2])

    print "check: "



    vat_number = vat_number.strip()
    country_code = country_code.strip()
    response = None
    valid = False


    if country_code != 'None' and vat_number != 'None':
        print 'going to viet for: ', vat_number, country_code
        response = return_address( country_code, vat_number) 


    if response:
        valid = response['valid']

    company_name = "test"  #None
    address = "test"
    #address1 = response['address']
#############################################################################################    
    company_name =  response['name']


    if response and valid and country_code != '--':
        #print 'response: '
        print 'response: ', response['name'], response['address']
        company_name =  response['name']
        address =  response['address']



    else: 
        breaker = 0

        print "FOUND: ", address, company_name
        print 'IN ELSE'

        for j in range(len(rows2)):
            vat2 = str(rows2[j][1])

            if vat_number == vat2: # match is there
                address = str(rows2[j][2])
                company_name = str(rows2[j][4])
                breaker = 1
                #s.encode('utf-8')


                print "FOUND: ", vat2, address, company_name

            if breaker == 1:
                break



    #### UPDATE
    #print 'before update: ', address, company_name
    cursor.execute("UPDATE test SET company_adress = %s , company_name=%s WHERE uid = '" + uID +"'",  ( address, company_name))


    cursor.execute("UPDATE oldcompany SET company_adress = %s , company_name=%s WHERE vat_number = '" + vat_number +"'",  ( address, company_name))
conn.commit()
```

cursor.execute("SELECT `uid`, `invoice_nr`, `company_name`, `company_adress` FROM test ")
print("query after commit:")
print(cursor.fetchall())

Comment: I see nothing in your code that looks like SOAP. Please [edit] your question and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, me and copy&paste is not a friend. I think I get all the code now.